# I am not able to see the value of variable in jsp page when i hover the mouse on it

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, hover

I am not able to see the value of the variable in JSP page. When I hover the mouse on it. It shows the type of the class. I am in debug mode and I am checking the variable after the line is executed. It works absolutely fine. When I see variables in java file. both the files are in the same project.

`window >> preference>>java/j2ee>>editor>>hovers`

....combined hovers are checked...

Comment: eclipse s the ide used

Comment: select the variable (by mouse) and press ctrl+shift+i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into same issue recently. I found [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40564/how-can-i-debug-a-jsp). It might be helpful for you.

Also one quick workaround is that you can punch out `System.out.println()` statements to check the values. It might be painful though, and make sure to remove them once you are done.

Comment: OK so I learnt that there is no straightforward way to inspect the variable values. One simple way is to use sysout statements as I already mentioned in the answer. I am not sure if at all there is a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

select The variable and

**press Cntrl + shift + i**

and you will get value of selected variable in debug mode